# Предлагаю объединить метки “сказуемое” и “сказуемые”

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки

Предлагаю объединить метки “сказуемое” и “сказуемые”. Мы отдаем предпочтение множественному числу. Тогда пусть метка “сказуемые” будет главной, а “сказуемое” – синонимом.

Answer (score 1):

Я объединил метки и создал синонимы. Теперь все будет как надо. Спасибо за помощь!